# what is the equivalent of an edge physics body without a sprite in Unity

Tags: sprite-kit, unity-game-engine

From a Swift SpriteKit perspective an edge physics body can easily be created specifying the dimensions of the rectangle without an image in the following way:

```
    let borderEdgeRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, 0.5 , CGRectGetHeight(frame)*0.8)
    let borderEdge = SKNode()
    borderEdge = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: borderEdgeRect)
    addChild(borderEdge)
```

How can an equivalent edge be created in Unity for a 2d game, specifying the rect without an image, something  line an invisible wall or boundary?

Comment: The simplest way would be a sprite with alpha at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Box Collider 2D or any other Collider to an empty Gameobject.

[image]